# What if I do not bind a function or method in the class component of React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

*First, have a look at this simple code, which is just updating a count through two buttons with different values.*

```js
import "./App.css";
import React, { Component } from "react";

class App extends React.Component {
  // Initialising state
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      count: 0,
    };
    // Not binding the handler function
    // this.handler.bind(this)
  }

  // Not using a arrow function
  handler(number) {
    // Changing the state
    this.setState((state) => ({ count: state.count + number }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Count: {this.state.count}</h1>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            this.handler(+1);
          }}
        >
          Increase By +1
        </button>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            this.handler(-1);
          }}
        >
          Decrease By -1
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**Here I need to know that neither I am binding the `handler method` nor using an arrow function. Then why is it working fine?**

In the [react documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#:%7E:text=constructor(props)%20%7B%0A%20%20super(props)%3B%0A%20%20//%20Don%27t%20call%20this.setState()%20here!%0A%20%20this.state%20%3D%20%7B%20counter%3A%200%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20this.handleClick%20%3D%20this.handleClick.bind(this)%3B%0A%7D), it is mentioned that you must bind a handler method to use it.

**One more explanation is needed from the side: why do we need to bind our method?**

Comment: When you reference `this` in any class method, it refers to the class' `this`, just like in the constructor. That's why `this.setState` works. That's also the behavior in prototypial inheritance --> `App.prototype.handler = function() { this.setState(...); /* still works */ }`.

Comment: you need to bind if you are using `this` inside the method .... if its an arrow function it gets its `this` from its lexical `this`

Answer (score 0):

One more explanation is needed from the side: why do we need to bind our method?

It is require to bind with current this reference.